# What's the fastest, most efficient way to toggle > 10000 checkboxes with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, optimization

I have a `div` with more than 10000 checkboxes in it.

For now, take it as a technical limitation that I have 10000 checkboxes. It can't and won't change. This is not a homework.

```html
<div class="well well-sm" style="min-height: 100px; max-height: 360px; overflow: auto; background-color: #f7f7f7;">

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" name="some_name" value="28" checked="checked"> Item 1
        </label><br />

<!-- another 10000 of these -->
</div>
```

and this jQuery code that activates when specific buttons are pressed.

```
        $('.select-all').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:visible').prop('checked', true).change();
        });

        $('.unselect-all').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:visible').prop('checked', false).change();
        });

        $('.select-inverse').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:visible').click();
        });
```

(Ignore the `:visible` part as the list could be filtered)

When the number of checkboxes is in the thousands the whole thing gets too slow, especially when ~10000 checkboxes need to be toggled.

I was wondering if there's a faster (not necessarily better) way to toggle all of them at the same time (mostly for select/unselect all, as inverse selection can be removed altogether)

Comment: @ASDFGerte Why does it matter? Can you answer the question?

Comment: @nickpapoutsis Because if you need 10000 checkboxes on a single page you might have a problem that should be solved by other means. Maybe there's a much better way to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Modus Tollens The "much better way" is some kind of pagination but that's not what I want to do. Having 10000+ checkboxes won't change under any circumstances.

Comment: @nickpapoutsis if it's some sort of mass listing, and you want to be able to do bulk operations for it, it's better to paginate results by 50-100 per page, and have a seperate single line batch operation, with one select box that serves the purpose of "all", or selected, and another one to choose the action.

Comment: @nickpapoutsis I see, but could I still ask "why"? This would provide valuable context. It would be my first question in real life, too, when helping a co-worker. This sounds so wrong that I'd see context as vital.

Comment: @nickpapoutsis - Your selector is slowing you down, why do you need `:visible`? Why do you need `:checkbox`? Add a class to your checkboxes and be done with it.

Comment: Worth pointing out the depending on your logic that you have inside `bound` change handlers to these checkboxes, then my comment may or may not help you.

Comment: @KetchupGod I already mentioned I don't want to do pagination and can't have an "all" check checkbox because the list may be filtered (full-text search and such) so "all" doesn't exist.

Comment: @ModusTollens It's a simple (full-text filtered) list and you can check all the boxes you want. The 10000 checkboxes will exist because that's the number of items that exist and need to be shown to the end-user. It's either no pagination and 10000 checkboxes or pagination and x number of checkboxes per page. I don't want to do pagination, I want to improve the 10000 checkboxes on a single page.

Comment: @Adam Some items may be hidden so I need to select only the `:visible` .

Comment: @nickpapoutsis Well, paginations exist especially for cases like this. Let alone checking all of them, even DOM render will take quite some time. I've worked on millions of records listed with pagination, being filterable, and still bulk operable. With your latest addition, you should know what your filters are if you're serving it on a page. You can just have a "filtered" option, instead of "all" or "selected", which will apply whatever you want to your current result because if you can retrieve them, you can query them for an update, too.

Comment: @KetchupGod Pagination isn't something I want to do for various reasons. 

DOM render is an issue but not enough to matter right now.

A "filtered" option can't really work because there's lots of other code that depends on individual checkboxes being check/unchecked (working around this might be doable but not really possible right now).

Think of this as a static page with no further access to the server/db.

Comment: @nickpapoutsis - you can still optimize your selector with classes, I have feeling that your hidden checkboxes probably belong inside an element that has a class detailing it's been hidden. First step is to try optimizing your selector. Second step is show why you are calling `change` manually on all these checkboxes - you must have listeners set up? You could probably solve that issue with better delegation I bet.

Comment: I imagine toggling that number of checkboxes would cause the UI to briefly lock up. If that is the case in practice, you could toggle (say) 500 at a time, sleep for a small while, do another 500, etc. That would keep the UI responsive while allowing for a large number of toggles to (eventually) take place.

Comment: @Adam You are right, there are listeners that depend on those changes on a per checkbox basis (but will soon change the code around that which is why I am only looking for optimizations for the 10000 toggles).
I'll have to spend some time doing tests with classes I guess.

Comment: @halfer Just the toggling action can be quite fast but because I will (soon) move to over 100000 checkboxes I want to optimize that part as much as possible.
Toggling in batches might work but I'm not sure I know how to properly implement that within the current system.

Comment: How long does it take with your current code to toggle 10,000 checkboxes? Does it lock up the browser UI?

Comment: @nickpapoutsis `I will (soon) move to over 100000 checkboxes`. I am fully aware you don't want to hear this but just stop, please, just stop. The couple of people who are interested in helping you out in these comments are trying to get your current code to work, not provide an extensible solution (because it's not extensible!). Think up alternate UI scenarios - instead of checking 1000000 checkboxes, when the "check all" box is clicked, just hide the massive list and store some state that says everything is checked to be done with it. Stop the madness.

Comment: @halfer I can get it down to 1-2 secs for `prop` and 10-15 secs for `click` (which isn't that important and could be removed if needed). It does lock the browser (tab) UI up.

Comment: @Adam haha NO! 100000 is the absolute worst case scenario and almost no one will ever (need to) deal with something so huge but I want to be able to offer it if needed.
I am not interested in talking about alternative UI scenarios because you haven't seen the rest of the code and I won't post it here since it's being worked on and will change a lot.
The only reason I asked this question is because I am looking for an optimized solution that's better than mine. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @nickpapoutsis: I would go with short bursts of DOM changes then, with small sleeps between each set. I think that is the best you will achieve with the constraints that you have.

Comment: @nickpapoutsis - fix the selector, and delegate the `change` listener instead of applying it individually to each checkbox if you already haven't (and don't call `change` for each checkbox, call something like `updateChanged` that will go and get all the checked/unchecked checkboxes and do the necessary work in a single function call rather than 10000). That will solve as much of your problem as you possibly can with these requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know how much you loved my 10000 checkboxes so since I recently moved to 50000 checkboxes I figured it would be fun to post an answer (maybe I'll get enough downvotes to keep me going till the ultimate target of 100000 checkboxes on a single page).

I updated the HTML since last time to this:

```html
<div class="well  well-sm  top" data-textarea-target="name-of-target">
    <div class="checkbox-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="some_name" id="28" value="28" checked="checked">
        <label for="28">
            <span class="well-text-style-1">Item 1</span>
            <span class="well-text-style-2">subtitle</span>
        </label>
    </div>
<!-- another 50000 of these -->
</div>
```

and this is the code for the buttons that can now manipulate 50000 checkboxes in 2-4 seconds:

```js
    $('.select-all').click(function () {
        // we check all visible checkboxes
        $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:visible').prop('checked', true);
        // other code here that calls functions to handle the removal of .change()
    });

    $('.unselect-all').click(function () {
        // we uncheck all visible checkboxes
        $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:visible').prop('checked', false);
        // other code here that calls functions to handle the removal of .change()
    });


    $('.select-inverse').click(function () {
        // we uncheck the visible, checked ones and check the visible, unchecked ones
        $(this).parent().find(':checkbox:visible').prop( "checked", function( i, val ) {
            return !val;
        });
        // other code here that calls functions to handle the removal of .click()
    });
```

The only thing that has changed is we removed the .change() and added code that replicates its functionality once all checkboxes have been manipulated.

This has resulted in being able to check/uncheck 50000 checkboxes in as little as 1-2 seconds and 3-4 seconds on average.